# Is it possible to delete (not just unlink) a class?

Tags: python, class

Suppose I define a class.

```
>>> class A(object):
>>>     pass
```

Then I want to delete that class. I can use `del` to unlink it from the variable `A`.

```
>>> del A
>>> A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

But `del` does not actually remove the class itself. I can tell this because it's still listed among `object`'s subclasses.

```
>>> object.__subclasses__()
[..., <class '__main__.A'>]
```

Not that I think this will work, but...

```
>>> del object.__subclasses__()[-1]
>>> object.__subclasses__()
[..., <class '__main__.A'>]
```

Is there a way to actually remove the class so that it is no longer in `object.__subclasses__()`?

Comment: just out of curiousity why would you want to do this? that said it is kind of an interesting question I havent ever seen.

Comment: If you're using iPython: `%reset -f`... but why would you ever *need* to remove the class from `object.__subclasses__` in the first place?

Comment: I'm using `__subclasses__()` to get a list of children from a base class for use in the [strategy pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) so that I can dynamically select one based on a string identifier. I'm writing tests for it, but I don't want the classes defined in one test to leak into other tests, so I'd like to clean them up if possible.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Usually, you don't need the strategy pattern in Python because functions are first class values, so you can simply pass the function rather than needing a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weak references to `A` will stick around after you `del A`.  One reason this is necessary is to allow cyclic references without preventing garbage collection.  Try this to see what is still referencing it (this is specific to the python interpreter, may vary if you run as a script file):

```
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
...
>>> A
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> del A
>>> A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined

>>> object.__subclasses__()[-2]
<class '__main__.A'>

>>> # using weakref
>>> import weakref
>>> weakref.getweakrefs(object.__subclasses__()[-2])
[<weakref at 0x800fa4ba8; to 'type' at 0x800f9d420 (A)>]

>>> # Another method using gc to see the referrers:
>>> import gc
>>> gc.collect()
>>> gc.get_referrers(object.__subclasses__()[-2])
[<__main__.A object at 0x800face90>, (<class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>), <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>]

>>> # See the referents
>>> print '\n'.join(map(str, gc.get_referents(object.__subclasses__()[-2])))
{'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None}
(<class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
(<type 'object'>,)
<type 'object'>
```

More reading on the subject:

http://pymotw.com/2/weakref/
https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/weakref.html
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0205/
[https://docs.python.org/release/2.6.4/library/stdtypes.html#class.**subclasses**](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6.4/library/stdtypes.html#class.__subclasses__)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gc.collect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) after deleting:

```
del A
from gc import collect
collect()
print( object.__subclasses__())
```

Comment: There is a reference to it, reachable by `object.__subclasses__()`. Obviously `gc.collect` won't help.

Comment: @letitbee Why don't you just try it? Also, `object.__subclasses__()` is a method, it does not reference the class. (The returned value does but only as long as it exists.)

Comment: You are right, it helps - must be a weakref somewhere. The argument that 'method does not reference the class' though just does not make any sense...

Comment: @letitbee The method is built-in (implemented in C). There does not need to be any weakref.